# google apiclient for searching images in python

Tags: python, google-api-client

I want to get the url of images resulting from a query to Google apiclient.discovery. Using the code below I can get the first 10 images, but when I add the field 'start' in the query to iterate for the next 10 images, I get this error message:

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com....."Invalid Value">

My code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

curr_idx = 0
service = build("customsearch", "v1",developerKey="***mykey***")
for query in range(3):
    res = service.cse().list(
        q='cat',
        cx='***myengine***',
        searchType='image',
        start=curr_idx,
        num=10,
    ).execute()

    for item in res['items']:
        print item['title']
        curr_idx = curr_idx + 1
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. curr_idx has to be a string and the initial value should be 1 instead of 0. So this is the final code

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

curr_idx = 1
service = build("customsearch", "v1",developerKey="***mykey***")
for query in range(3):
    res = service.cse().list(
        q='cat',
        cx='***myengine***',
        searchType='image',
        start=str(curr_idx),
        num=10,
    ).execute()

    for item in res['items']:
        print item['title']
        curr_idx = curr_idx + 1
```